# Reboot required for changes to take effect in DirectAdmin

Tags: apache-2.2

Recently there is a fault in DirectAdmin's underlying scripts that after a user is created with respective domains, DA failes to reload the Apache service for the new configuration to take effect which leads to the 404 error upon calling the said domain.

I wonder what could be the problem and how could it be fixed?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure where the problem might be, but rebooting the server doesn't seem to be a wise choice. Try first to reload (or restart) the `named` service:

```
service named restart
```

By doing that you can be sure that it's a DNS-related issue. Then you should look into `/var/log/messages` to search for errors on `named` service or other issues. Also, you might want to check Directadmin's log files: `/var/log/directadmin/error.log` and `/var/log/directadmin/errortaskd.log`